# SVG: Drop Shadow Colour / Inset Shadow with Colour

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to know how do I change the shadow colour with a specified RGB or hex value on a SVG shape.

And also how to easily convert it to an inset shadow and back to drop shadow similar to the CSS3 box shadow function.

http://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/1jb3jdpc/

```
<svg width="200" height="200" style="overflow: visible">
<defs>
<filter id="boxshadow">
<feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="50" />
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
</filter>
</defs>
<polygon filter="url(#boxshadow)" style="fill:yellow;stroke:blue;stroke-width:8" points="32,0 160,0 192,101 160,202 32,202 0,101" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You want the shadow to be grey rather than use the shape colours?

Comment: @RobertLongson The shadow colour is dynamic, it has to be any colour from a colour picker in RGB/Hex format. For an example using #F00 for red drop shadow.

Comment: SVG does not support that. You'd have to code a specific colour into the drop shadow or use the shape's colours as you are doing. Alternatively use a CSS filter per http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty although those don't work in IE